# Python parse xml with find or findall module

Tags: python, xml

I would like to parse this XML and display the result of the Memory and Swap

```
<rpc>
<show>
  <memory>
    <physical-memory>
      <memory-info>
        <type>Memory</type>
        <total-in-kb>3524384</total-in-kb>
        <used-in-kb>3401028</used-in-kb>
      </memory-info>
      <memory-info>
        <type>Swap</type>
        <total-in-kb>0</total-in-kb>
        <used-in-kb>0</used-in-kb>
      </memory-info>
    </physical-memory>
  </memory>
</show>
```

`tree=et.fromstring('file.xml')`

`print(tree.find('rpc/show/memory/physical-memory/memory-info/type[@test='Memory']/total-in-kb).text')`

is it a way to do like that : just in one line with find of findall ?
as I have a lot of metric to collect, I would like to use a liste of them and avoid to do a loop for some of them.

Comment: `[@att=‘value]` is for attributes - use `[type=‘Memory’]` to test the text below tag `type`. The xpath syntax supported by ElementTree is documented below the headings ‘Supported xpath syntax’ here https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Comment: Thanks a lot ! It works !!! 

Answer (score 0):

Solution using lxml:

```
from lxml import etree as et

root = et.fromstring(xml)
xpath = '//memory-info[./type/text()=$type]//total-in-kb/text()'
memory = root.xpath(xpath, type='Memory')
swap = root.xpath(xpath, type='Swap')
print(memory, swap)
```

For finding both at once:

```
from lxml import etree as et

root = et.fromstring(xml)
xpath = '//memory-info[./type/text()="Memory" or ./type/text()="Swap"]//total-in-kb/text()'
lst = root.xpath(xpath)
print(lst)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I didn't success with the installation of the module lxml , but it works with this module "import xml.etree.cElementTree as et" and this request "print(tree.find('rpc/show/memory/physical-memory/memory-info/[type=\'Memory\']/total-in-kb').text)"